# why node tells me "jwt must be provided" although the token is there?

Tags: mean-stack, express-jwt

i kinda cannot find a valid reason why i am getting that error. I am trying to build blog functionality myself for creating, commenting, liking a post in mean app using a middelware function to check if the user is authenticated. In all the activties it works fine but the like function! When i console log the token in the middleware function the token gets normally printed on the screen but the like-route dosen't identify it. Here is my Code:

```
router.post('/:id/like', checkToken, (req, res)=>{
console.log(req.token);// undefined

jwt.verify(req.token, 'natsu1piece', (err, auth)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.json({err:err});
    }else { 
      User.findOne({_id:auth.id}, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json({err:err})
        }
         Post.findById(req.params.id, (err, post)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json({err:err})
        }
        if(post._id===user._id){
            res.json({err:'you cannot like your own post'})
        }
        const like ={
            likerId: user._id,
            likerName: user.username
        }
        post.likes.push(like);
        post.save(err=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({err})
            }
            res.json({message: 'you liked that post'})
        })
    })
    })}

})
```

})

And here is the checkAuth middleware:

```
  // check authentication middleware
function checkToken(req, res, next){
const tokenBearer= req.headers.authorization;
if(typeof tokenBearer !== 'undefined'){
  const bearer = tokenBearer.split(' ');
  const token = bearer[1];
  req.token = token;
  console.log(req.token) // prints the sent token successfully

}
next();

}
```

i have the following function for adding a comment and it works very fine with the same middleware:

```
  router.post('/:id/delete-comment', checkToken, (req, res)=>{
   jwt.verify(req.token, 'natsu1piece', (err, auth)=>{
    if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.json({err:err});
    return;
    }
    Post.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: req.params.id},
    {
        $pull:{
        comments:{_id:  req.body.id}
    }},
      err=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.json({err:err});
    }
    }

    )
   })
   })
```

Sorry for the very long post :)

Comment: post.userId === user._id*